# Texture shown in Viewport is white in Render

Tags: materials

The street texture is in the viewport but not in Render what have i done wrong?
-> see in the pictures[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: can be a lot of reasons. If you don't want us to guess...you should provide your blend file

Comment: First thing I always look for in situations like this are objects that are hidden in the viewport - hidden objects will still show in renders.

Comment: Perfect There was a white plane hidden in the viewport thanks!